# Precision vs. specificity

Tags: classification, model-evaluation, accuracy, sensitivity-specificity, precision

I know that if we cannot afford to have false positive results, we should aim for high precision.

My question is, how is precision different from specificity?

Any examples?

Answer (score 2):

Precision is *TP / (TP + FP)* and specificity is *TN / (TN + FP)*, where *TP* is true positives, *FP* is false positives, and *TN* is true negatives, as described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity). So if you look at the graphic from Wikipedia, precision considers the inner circle (fraction of positives in all selected elements), while specificity the right column (fraction of true negatives in all negatives). They are very different, as they measure different things.

[image: Sensitivity and specificity graphic from Wikipedia.]

Comment: I usually look at these terms with use cases, looking at 'when' to use section in this explanation [link](https://iq.opengenus.org/precision-recall-sensitivity-specificity/). 
I can't see a difference here in usage, precision is used "When the occurrence of false positives is Unacceptable", and specificity is used "When you don't want to frighten people with misleading information."

Comment: @MxML I'm not going to comment on some oversimplified explanations from a random website. You'll understand it better when you look at the formulas. They are quite simple and self-explanatory. The formulas are very different and consider different things.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, precision and specificity are related. In fact, all else equal, increasing the specificity will increase the precision. This makes sense. Precision is the credibility of a claim that a case is positive: when a case is identified as being positive, what is the probability that the case really is positive. Improving specificity means that fewer negative cases are mistaken for positive cases, giving greater credibility to a claim that a case is positive.

Comment: This is true, because they both want the false positive number to be small.

Answer (score 0):

Specificity is recall for negatives.

```
recall      = TP/(TP+FN)
specificity = TN/(TN+FP)
```

What this means is that recall is how good you are at finding all true positives (if I say something is NOT positive, it isn't).

Specificity, on the other hand, is how good you are at finding all negatives (if I say something is NOT negative, it is not)

Answer (score -1):

You can think of precision and specificity in terms of positive and negative cases. Precision is the likelihood that a given positive prediction is actually positive, specificity is the likelihood that a given negative prediction is actually negative. You could say that specificity is precision in the negative case.